# Meaning of the symbol: top clockwise arrow $\curvearrowright$ (html code &#8631;)

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, notation, representation-theory

In Tachikawa's book on ${\cal N}=2$ Supersymmetric dynamics for pedestrians (pg 72 https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2684), he uses a symbol ↷.

$F$ is the flavor symmetry group and $G$ is the gauge group.

$F, G$  ↷ $\mathbb{R}^n$

for a non-supersymmetric theory wiht $n$ real scalars $\phi^i$.
It would be nice if someone could tell the meaning of the symbol and also what it is used more generally for in mathematics. I am new to this and have never seen this symbol before. Maybe it is a symbol fequently used in mathematics. It is called top clockwise arrow and its unicode number is U+21B7.

Comment: This is a book “for pedestrians” and it doesn’t explain its (obscure) notation?

Comment: Can't see a reference to that symbol and I wonder if it might be a question of [mathematics.se] ?

Comment: The symbol is `\curvearrowright` from the AMS TeX symbols package: $\curvearrowright$. Apparently it used to denote a Borel action, here in the context of Lie group theory. The curved arrow in the other direction (`\curvearrowleft`, $\curvearrowleft$) apparently denotes a Borel action in the other direction. (That other symbol is used on the next page in the linked paper.) And with that, I am totally out of my league.

Comment: @DavidHammen I'd call that an answer if it wasn't a comment. :-)

Comment: @StephenG But I'm clueless regarding what that means. QMechanic's link to the group action wiki page is complete gobbledygook to me. I'm out of my league.

Comment: @DavidHammen Me too ! :-)

Comment: @StephenG What I did to arrive at that comment was some basic detective work. I knew from just looking at the linked arXiv paper that the referenced symbol was not an HTML symbol; it was either TeX or LaTeX. It's blatantly obvious when a paper is written in TeX/LaTeX; nothing else looks that good. I soon found that the symbol was `\curvearrowright`, and then I found papers (mostly math papers) that used that symbol. And they read like gobbledegook, totally out of my league.

Comment: Finally, I verified that `\curvearrowright` was indeed the symbol being used by downloading the source for the referenced paper. And there it was, `\curvearrowright` in the "Hypermultiplets revisited" section, and also `\curvearrowleft` in subsequent expressions.

Comment: @DavidHammen In case you (or anyone else) finds it useful and is not aware of it, there's [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to help identify Tex for symbols.

Comment: The question (v3) asks about an HTML entity which, on my system, is shaped like a shepherd’s crook or a rotated J, with a letter-height vertical segment and a semicircular arrow on top. However the shape in the paper, reproduced on this page with `\curvearrowright`, is a semicircular arrow without any vertical segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $G \curvearrowright X$ often denotes a [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $G\times X\to X$, cf. above comment by David Hammen. See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/64544/13917) related MO.SE post.